# Does java recursion algorithms consume more heap causing additional garbage collection?

Tags: java

If I have two algorithms that produce the same results, where the first is based on recursion and the other is a loop based one, which will cause more garbage collection with regards to pure program flow management ?

Comment: Your question as it is - doesn't make much sense. Please elaborate, may be with some sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursion alone will cause additional *stack* use, as each layer of the call is a new element in the call stack, but will not use any extra heap (aside from perhaps a small object or two uses to keep track of stack information - those may be allocated on the heap, I am not sure).

However, in a typical recursive algorithm, any extra heap objects will likely not last very long, and will be cleaned up in the next young generation collection. So they won't result in very much more garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

JVM keeps stack frames separately from heap. So they are not garbage collected. Recursion will not affect heap as long as you dont initialize objects inside method calls. Here is an [article](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-stack-heap.html). But still its slower than iteration because additional time to allocate stack frame is still needed.

Comment: But call/return is quite fast compared to the cost of allocating an object.

Answer (score 1):

Basically (over-simplified), Java memory is divided into two segments, the stack and the heap.  Call/returns are kept track of in the stack, in an obvious fashion where an entry is "pushed" on a call and "popped" on return.  This scheme is "self managing", and does not need garbage collection to keep it tidy.

Of course, other heap-based objects may be allocated in each call frame, but that has nothing to do with recursion.  And generally speaking if one uses a recursive algorithm it eliminates the need for a data structure to track progress that would have been heap-allocated in the non-recursive case.